# Need help on mapping Json (JsonNode) to Java Object

Tags: java, json, playframework

We get the existing Json response from one of our services:

```
{
  "CustomerInfoResponse": [
    {
      "CustomerInfo": {
        "customerId": "17414101",
        "customerCode": "41020393888"
      }
    },
    {
      "CustomerInfo": {
        "customerId": "17414100",
        "customerCode": "41020393888"
      }
    },
    {
      "CustomerInfo": {
        "customerId": "17414099",
        "customerCode": "41020393888"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

We map this using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode on the following class below:

```
public class CustomerInfoResponse {

    @JsonProperty(value = "CustomerInfoResponse")
    private List<CustomerInfo> customerInfo;


    public List<CustomerInfo> getCustomerInfo() {
        return customerInfo;
    }


    public void setCustomerInfo(final List<CustomerInfo> customerInfo) {
        this.customerInfo = customerInfo;
    }
}
```

and

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = Id.NAME)
public class CustomerInfo {

    private String customerId;
    private String customerCode;


    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerCode() {
        return customerCode;
    }

    public void setCustomerCode(String customerCode) {
        this.customerCode = customerCode;
    }
}
```

Now the Json format is being changed to the one below. I am new to Json Mapping and I would like to get an idea on what would change to my Java Classes

```
{
  "CustomerInfo": [
    {
      "customerId": "112217",
      "customerCode": "41020393888"
    },
    {
      "customerId": "112218",
      "customerCode": "41020393888"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: refer your previous response class and try to code the new one for new json, show your code if you still face the problem

Comment: Gson is very easy to use. If you want, search for it on google, or read more here: https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0):

To map from the modified Json you should:

1. Change the annotation of the member customerInfo to the value, which appears in Json - **CustomerInfo** instead of the previous **CustomerInfoResponse**. Note, that **value=** may be omitted.
2. Remove annotation from the class CustomerInfo

The modified Java classes should be like this:

```
public class CustomerInfoResponse {

    @JsonProperty("CustomerInfo")
    private List<CustomerInfo> customerInfo;

    ...
}

public class CustomerInfo {

    private String customerId;
    private String customerCode;
    ...
}
```

It is not necessary, but is the good practice to annotate class members with JsonProperty annotations. This decouples names, used in the class, from Json keys. So, it will be like this:

```
 public class CustomerInfo {
    @JsonProperty("customerId")
    private String customerId;
    @JsonProperty("customerCode")
    private String customerCode;
    ...
}
```

Regarding Gson - you cannot use it with Play.

Comment: Thank you Asch for your answers, I will try it out later and let you know how it goes. I Actually came very close to what you suggested but I did not do #2. I did some searches on what @JsonTypeInfo(include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = Id.NAME) means but @JsonTypeInfo(include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = Id.NAME) of the reference I found where vague. Can you tell me what this annotation does and why I need to remove it?